# Coloring a curve in the 3D space with CSV data

Tags: csv, plot, colors, 3d, wolfram-mathematica

I've been struggling with this situation for days already and I would really appreciate a piece of advice.

I have a simulation running in C++ and in the end I get a .csv file  with 4 columns: t, L_1(t), L_2(t), L_3(t).

The function I want to plot is L(t) = L_1(t)**i** + L_2(t)**j** + L_3(t)**k** , L(0) = (0,0,0).

I'd like to plot it in a 3D chart the path the function L(t) walks trough the time in the data sheet. Also, I'd like the (log of) the time as as a colour scale as well, denoting the evolution path of the function.

I tried several options, but none really made it the I intended. Could you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is easiest to do directly as a `Line` graphic:

```
 data = Table[ { t, Sin[t] , Cos[t] , (t/20)^2 } , {t, 0, 20, .5 }];
 Graphics3D@Line[ data[[All, 2 ;; 4]]]
```

[image]

you can color this using `VertexColors`

you can also do interpolation and then use `ParametricPlot3D`

```
 interp = Table[ Interpolation[data[[All, i]]] , {i, 2, 4}]
 ParametricPlot3D[Through@interp[t], {t, 1, 40}]
```

[image]

with this you can play with `InterpolationOrder` option to control smoothing.

In color (and with `InterpolationOrder->1` )

```
 ParametricPlot3D[Through@interp[t], {t, 1, 40},
       ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t}, Hue[t]]]
```

[image]